# cassandra 1.2 memory per CF basis

Tags: cassandra

how much is the default memory size that consider for per CF in cassandra 1.2?

in previous edition it was 128 MB. and it was declare in  MemtableThroughputInMB parameter in cassandra.yaml file. but now i cant find it in cassandra 1.2 config file.

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

It is replaced by memtable_total_space_in_mb.

(Default: 1/3 of the heap**) Specifies the total memory used for all memtables on a node. This replaces the per-table storage settings memtable_operations_in_millions and memtable_throughput_in_mb.

Answer (score 0):

Now a days cassandra does not provide you the scope to set the default memory size per column family basis. Rather you can define the whole size of the memtable in your configuration i.e .yaml file using **memtable_total_space_in_mb**. By default its value is one third of your JVM  heap size.

Cassandra manages this space across all your ColumnFamilies and flushes memtables to disk as needed. Do note that a minimum of 1MB per memtable is used by the per-memtable arena allocator , which is worth keeping in mind if you are looking at going from thousands to tens of thousands of ColumnFamilies.